# R Shiny equivalent in Python? Creating a window-based tool

Tags: python, r, web-applications, shiny, plotly-dash

I am trying to transfer an app i build in R Shiny to Python Code.
It's main use is to set the input parameters for a data analysis to be run which should create and output pdf file.

So far I managed to understand that DASH might be the tool to go with. But is there a way to launch a DASH app in an external window (not in a browser window)? Like the following:

[image]

After setting the Input values I want to have a button to click "Run" or something similiar to run the underlying code and generate a PDF Report. How would you do that with Python and do you maybe know a good Tutorial how to build a basic app like this?

Comment: I've found references to streamlit, but I haven't used it yet.  


https://www.streamlit.io/

Comment: I went with Dash, as my server issue could be solved. But streamlit looks promising as well thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean in the first part of your question. You may be able to use an IDE with integrated broswer to view your app during developement if you don't want to use a broswer. But the whole point of dash is to be a web based application, so it would be best on a browser.

Alternately, you can save the rendered output from browser to a .html file if you need to share it without having a live server host your application.

For the second part of your question, for a button click to generate a pdf report, refer to the documentation of [callback](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks) in dash.

The callback function for the `Run Analysis` button can then be something on the lines of

```
def generate_report():
    #Code to generate required pdf
    # Code to download on client 
    return link_to_pdf
```

Hope this gives some pointers in the direction.

Comment: thanks for the reply I will have a look into it. And yeah you're right there should be no need to launch an app in an external window.